How would I calculate the gravity at a given depth on a planet with two distinct layers with different densities?
If you assume a planet to be one density then gravity just scales linearly from the centre to the surface, and you can use the surface gravity equation.
How would you go about working out the gravity at a certain depth if you said your planet had a core of radius $R_a$ with a density $p_a$ and an outer layer of radius $R_b$ with a density $p_b$?
The inspiration for this is Europa (Jupiter's moon) which (we think) has oceans with depths that are roughly 10% of the radius of the planet.
I had been trying to figure out how to offset the matter at a greater radius than the chosen point against the matter closer to the centre and on the other side. (Although I see that was the wrong direction now that people have made me aware of the Shell Theorem)

Can you write an equation for the mass below radius r?

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

By the shell theorem we can just completely ignore the matter at greater radius. It's all about calculating the enclosed mass within a volume less than the current radius ($r$) using the density formula for enclosed mass within a sphere of radius $r$:
$$(M_{\text{enc}} = 4/3 \pi r^3 \times p)$$
To calculate the force on the external surface of a shell of matter (e.g. the shell of water on Europa) you calculate the gravity due to a complete sphere of water with the same radius as the outer radius of the shell and then subtract the gravity due a smaller sphere of water, with a radius equivalent to the inner radius of the shell. This gives us the gravity due the water shell only. Then you add back in the gravity due to the more dense inner sphere which is just the normal calculation. We can break down the gravitational field of a dual density object like Europa into 3 distinct regions:
$$F=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{4}{3} \pi Gm p_a r & \mbox{if }   r<R_a\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\pi Gm}{r^2}  \left( (p_a-p_b) R_a^3 + p_b r^3  \right) & \mbox{if } R_a \le r \lt R_b\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\pi Gm}{r^2} \left( (p_a-p_b) R_a^3 + p_b R_b^3  \right) & \mbox{if } r \ge R_b \end{cases}$$
You can continue this process for any number of shells.
GeoGebra construction here
E.g. for 4 regions:
$$F=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{4}{3} \pi Gm p_a r & \mbox{if }   R_a>r\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\pi Gm}{r^2}  \left( p_aR_a^3 + p_b (r^3-R_a^3)  \right) & \mbox{if } R_a \le r \lt R_b\\[4pt]  
\dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\pi Gm}{r^2}  \left( p_aR_a^3 + p_b (R_b^3-R_a^3) + p_c (r^3-R_b^3)   \right) & \mbox{if } R_b \le r \lt R_c\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\pi Gm}{r^2} \left(  p_aR_a^3 + p_b (R_b^3-R_a^3) + p_c (R_c^3-R_b^3) \right) & \mbox{if } R_c \le r\end{cases}$$
The chart below represents the gravitational field of a planet with a dense core with a less dense ocean and an even lower density atmosphere, showing how the gravitational force varies with $r$:

Note that the only region with a linear relationship between the force and the radius is the core, where there is no change in average density with radius.

@Amit Nice edit. Looks much nicer :-)

By the shell theorem (allowable from the spherical symmetry you have imposed), the strength of the gravitational force at some depth will be the same as if all the mass of the planet at depths beneath you were located at the center, with no influence from mass above you. That is, if you are at some distance from the center $r=r_0$, then you can ignore all mass with $r>r_0$. So the gravitational acceleration at a distance $r$ from the center is given:
$$g(r)=\frac{GM(r)}{r^2}$$
where $M(r)$ is the total mass at a depth less than $r$.

So basically I can work out the gravity at the border between the two densities (gx) and at the surface (gy). Then the gravity is linear from 0 to gx and then linear from gx to gy. Right?

@SamDean It will be linear from the center to $R_A$, but it is not linear from $R_A$ to $R_B$ (although for $r\gg R_A$ linearity becomes a better approximation). You will find $g(r)$ for that region contains a term proportional to $r^{-2}$

Calling the force from layer $a$ ($b$) as $\vec F_a(\vec r)$ ($\vec F_b(\vec r)$), the total force due to both layers at $\vec r$ is:
$$ \vec F_{a+b}(\vec r) = \vec F_a(\vec r) + \vec F_b(\vec r) $$
Now you know how to compute the force from a uniform sphere. If you don't know how to model a shell, then you can model the system as two spheres:

A larger sphere of radius $R_b$ and density $\rho_b$.

An inner sphere with radius $R_a$ and density $\rho_a-\rho_b$


regardless of the sign of the latter, and just add them.
